# The Usage Limit in Google CSE

Tags: api, google-custom-search

I'm using Google CSE API.
But I face the usage limit on every single day.
I try to use my other account key and CSE key. 
But still, my application won't work when it reaches the usage-limit-a-day thing.

My question is:
1. What do I do to fix this?
2. How many requests exactly are there in Google CSE API? It said in the documentation that there was allowed 100 requests a day, but I have actually run my application for about just 10 times, and the usage limit stands in the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You would need to enable billing on your cloud console account.  You will then be paying 
   $5 per 1000 queries once you pass the free limit of 100/d.
2. The free limit is 100/d - yes this is very small and not enough for most use cases.  I don't know why you would only get 10/d.

CSE gives good data (in my limited, recent experience), but it is expensive.  Consider also Bing and Yahoo search products.